# I want to display one columns data sum on different columns based on where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is image which describe my requirements i have a column having different data i want its count on where condition where data=1 as col1 and where data = 2 as col2 and so on....

[image: Below is image which describe my requirements i have a column having different data i want its count on where condition where data=1 as col1 and where data = 2 as col2 and so on....]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE data WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Col1,
  COUNT(CASE data WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Col2,
  COUNT(CASE data WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Col3,
  COUNT(CASE data WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Col4
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    SUM(CASE WHEN data=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS col1,
          SUM(CASE WHEN data=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS col2
FROM      Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Link to [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf97af/4)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE data WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Col1,
  COUNT(CASE data WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Col2,
  COUNT(CASE data WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Col3,
  COUNT(CASE data WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Col4
FROM yourTable
```